# How to find the next match in Netbeans project tree search box

Tags: netbeans

If you type some characters in the project tree in Netbeans it highlights the file that contains a partial match. How can we trigger the next match search?

If I have 5 files containing word cycle then it will just highlight the first one. Can I press any key combination to make it cycle through all the matches quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To highlight the next match, Down Arrow <kbd>↓</kbd> is your solution.